# Cannot create new transaction because capacity was exceeded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-7

I receive this message after this command :

> "AdoConnection.BeginTrans"

and this happens after running a query with just one record as result.

I can't understand what is the problem! Is there any solution?

Comment: Seems like a few people have had this problem ... http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?321940-Cannot-create-new-transaction-because-capacity-was-exceeded&s=2398ad10c8ae7ca0efcb296b7f4d719e&p=1900705&viewfull=1#post1900705

Answer (score 0):

Quick search lead me to below,pasting here to avoid link rot

To resolve the errors, use one of the following workarounds:

- On the DataSetProvider Options property, make sure
  poFetchBlobsOnDemand and poFetchDetailsOnDemand are False.
- Use a BeforeApplyUpdates event to either call CloseDataSets
  or Close the connection:

> Procedure TForm1.DataSetProvider1BeforeApplyUpdates(Sender: TObject;
>              var OwnerData: OleVariant);
>            begin
>               SQLConnection1.CloseDataSets;
>               // SQLConnection1.Close;
>            end;

**References:**
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abc66f66-ffc0-4226-a28c-bab1bcdafce0/connect-delphi-2006-to-ms-sql-express?forum=sqlexpress